# xPath Query not available in command pallete

Tags: xml, visual-studio-code

I am not seeing XML Tools: in my command pallete (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>)

I think I just need to install something but I can't find anything on VS site or in the forum here.

Comment: Do you mean (ctrl + shift + p)?  That open the command pallete.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.  There are many options but not the XML tools.

Comment: I just installed the extension  - and then did the required reload - and I have the four XML Tools commands in the command palette.  Try uninstalling and re-install the extension?

Comment: Thanks Mark, I don't know why I didn't try that first.